# Modify an WSDL file programmatically

Tags: c#, wsdl

I want to automate the modification of a Wsdl. Currently I am loading the wsdl using:

```
string returnXML;

using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var credential = new NetworkCredential(userName, securelyStroredPassword, domain);
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    client.Credentials = credential;

    returnXML = client.DownloadString(url+wsdl);
}
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(returnXML);
```

I failed to apply some simple rules to the document:

Change soap:address location value to `url`

```
    <wsdl:service name="foo">
        <wsdl:port name="foo" binding="tns:foo">
            <soap:address location="WrongLocation"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
```

Add `maxOccurs="unbounded"` property to every `xs:element` that are in the `List<string> multipleOccurence`

```
    .Where(x=> multipleOccurence.Contains(x.name) )
```

Add  `minOccurs="0"` property to any `xs:element` that has a property `type="xs:string"`

For now I fail to select a simple know node:

```
var aNode = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/wsdl:definitions/wsdl:documentation/CreationInfo")
```

Example of Wsdl (not valid as many elements were cutoff to save some bit):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions >

    <wsdl:types>

        <xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Message" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Message">
            <xs:complexType name="MessageBody">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" namespace="##any"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:schema>

        <xs:schema>
            <xs:element name="RequestFooBar">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="Header">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="DocumentID" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="AlternateDocumentID" type="xs:string"/>

                                    <xs:element name="Foos">
                                        <xs:complexType>
                                            <xs:sequence>
                                                <xs:element name="Foo">
                                                    <xs:complexType>
                                                        <xs:sequence>
                                                            <xs:element name="Type" type="xs:string"/>
                                                            <xs:element name="Foo" type="xs:string"/>
                                                        </xs:sequence>
                                                    </xs:complexType>
                                                </xs:element>
                                            </xs:sequence>
                                        </xs:complexType>
                                    </xs:element>

                                    <xs:element name="Bars">
                                        <xs:complexType>
                                            <xs:sequence>
                                                <xs:element name="Bar">
                                                    <xs:complexType>
                                                        <xs:sequence>
                                                            <xs:element name="Type" type="xs:string"/>
                                                            <xs:element name="Bar" type="xs:string"/>
                                                            <xs:element name="ExternalBar" type="xs:string"/>
                                                        </xs:sequence>
                                                    </xs:complexType>
                                                </xs:element>
                                            </xs:sequence>
                                        </xs:complexType>
                                    </xs:element>
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>         
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>

            <xs:element name="ResponseFooBar">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="Ack">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="Code" type="xs:string"/>
                                    <xs:element name="Message" type="xs:string"/>
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>

        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>

    <wsdl:message name="FooBar_InputMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="part" element="tns:RequestFooBar"/>
    </wsdl:message>

    <wsdl:message name="Quotation_CreateQuotation_OutputMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="part" element="tns:ResponseFooBar"/>
    </wsdl:message>

    <wsdl:portType name="FOOFOO">
        <wsdl:documentation/>
        <wsdl:operation name="CreateQuotation">
            <wsdl:documentation/>
            <wsdl:input message="tns:FooBar_InputMessage"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:FooBar_OutputMessage"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>

    <wsdl:service name="foo">
        <wsdl:port name="foo" binding="tns:foo">
            <soap:address location="WrongLocation"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: Is a [past bin](https://pastebin.com/RyXkUhDh) of a Exemple Wsdl ok? As formated Wsdl can be quite long (100 lines); and it can be consider as an important part of an [mcve].

Comment: Then add it to the question; not as off-site resource and as comment.

Comment: @SebastianHofmann, I feel like the question is now drowned into a bit xml. but ok.

Comment: Still much better than a link.

Comment: Well their must be a simple way to handle this. Because Regex or string manipulation make it easy. but their must be a parser way.